Can a .NET Core System.ServiceModel WCF client specify non-standard default values?
I'm migrating some Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS apps to .NET 8.  These apps communicate with WCF services.  Previously, these apps used a Web Reference WCF Client (right-click project -> Add -> Web Reference) which added parameters and properties with the suffix "Specified" for any boolean and integer fields.  Now, we're migrating -to using a Connected Service WCF Client (right-click project -> Add -> Connected Service -> Add WCF Web Service), which is similar but doesn't have any "Specified" parameters or properties.
Overall, I don't miss the Specified parameters and properties since they were often unnecessary boilerplate.  However, there are a few places in our apps where we want a boolean variable to default to True instead of False if the server does not specify them.  In our use case, this would be due to the server being out of date and having an older version of the contract, although from my understanding EmitDefaultValue being set to False could also cause this and may be a more acceptable example of this problem.
Here's an example.
Version 1 of the service:
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://test.wcf.service")]
public interface IMobileCommunicationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestDTO Test();
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public string Hello;
}

Version 2 of the service:
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://test.wcf.service")]
public interface IMobileCommunicationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestDTO Test();
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public string Hello;

    public bool World;
}

TestDTO from a Reference.cs file for the WCF client.  Generated via a Web Reference which Xamarin apps can use:
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.8.9037.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SalesPad.DataCollection.Service")]
public partial class TestDTO {
    
    private string helloField;
    
    private bool worldField;
    
    private bool worldFieldSpecified;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public string Hello {
        get {
            return this.helloField;
        }
        set {
            this.helloField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    public bool World {
        get {
            return this.worldField;
        }
        set {
            this.worldField = value;
        }
    }
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool WorldSpecified {
        get {
            return this.worldFieldSpecified;
        }
        set {
            this.worldFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }
}

TestDTO from a Reference.cs file for the WCF client.  Generated via a Connected Service which .NET 8 Android and iOS apps can use:
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Tools.ServiceModel.Svcutil", "2.2.0-preview1.23462.5")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="TestDTO", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SalesPad.DataCollection.Service")]
public partial class TestDTO : object
{
    
    private string HelloField;
    
    private bool WorldField;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public string Hello
    {
        get
        {
            return this.HelloField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.HelloField = value;
        }
    }
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
    public bool World
    {
        get
        {
            return this.WorldField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.WorldField = value;
        }
    }
}

Code which the older client can use to default 'World' to 'true' if the service did not specify World's value, such as if the service was Version 1 of the service:
dto.World = dto.WorldSpecified ? dto.World : true;

I am fine with the WorldSpecified property not existing, since I don't care about the property itself.  But the WorldSpecified property provided a way for World to default to True instead of False if World isn't specified by the service.
Is there any way to get World to default to True with the newer Connected Service WCF client?
I tried adding a parameterless constructor to one of my DTO objects, but that constructor doesn't get called.  The only workarounds I can think of either involve manually changing the Reference.cs file (which I want to avoid since it'd be hard to maintain) or "sacrificing" the Hello field as part of a ridiculous hack which isn't worth trying to explain.

"Now, we're migrating to using System.ServiceModel, which is similar"  - Que? System.ServiceModel is WCF.

I don't really understand your needs at the moment, can you provide a code or legend to reproduce the problem?

Sorry, I didn't do a good job of explaining the problem is.  We're migrating to the System.ServiceModel NuGet packages, but yes, the old way was ultimately a different flavor of System.ServiceModel.  Also, I added code examples of how the service and client can be structured and what the problem is.

In C#, the default value for Boolean variables is false. Default values
So I think you can modify the code to:
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://test.wcf.service")]
public interface IMobileCommunicationService
{
    [OperationContract]
    TestDTO Test();
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public string Hello;

    public bool World=true;
}

Update:
I wrote an example for you to refer to:
IService1.cs:
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
    TestDTO Test(TestDTO testDTO);
}



[DataContract]
public class TestDTO
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool World=true;
}

Service1.svc
public TestDTO Test(TestDTO data)
 {
     data.World= true;
     return data;
 }

Client:
 ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
 TestDTO data = new TestDTO();
 data=client.Test(data);
 Console.WriteLine(data.World.ToString());
 Console.ReadLine();

Output:


Unfortunately that doesn't work since it only changes the default value server-side.  That change isn't picked up when generating the contract client-side.  I tried a DefaultValueAttribute too and that didn't work either.

I eventually figured out a way to do this which I don't entirely hate.  The jist of it is to create a custom DelegatingHandler, override SendAsync, and after calling the base method, call response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync to get the XML response.  From there, you can put the XML somewhere static and parse it to figure out which fields were in the XML.  Calling 'request.Headers.TryGetValues("SOAPAction"' can give which endpoint was called too.
It works, but it's still a bit frustrating since it feels like there should be a built-in way to do this.
